# Combine char to get char*

Tags: c++, c

Really dumb c++ question, but I don't see it covered in the way I need it to be.  I have a const char* that I want to pull various values out of and into their own char*.  For example

```
const char* atr;
//
//Data is placed in atr
//

//Here's what I want to do, but obviously this doesn't compile
char* _ts = atr[0] + atr[1];
char* _t0 = atr[2] + atr[3];
```

Thanks a ton in advance.  I'm a day to day C++ dev who was basically raised on C++11 and beyond, so dealing with character pointers is a bit strange to me.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate chars? Or are you trying to add byte values together?

Comment: this is pointer artihmetics, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm Your pointer `atr` is `const` therefore it always points to a specific location in memory. If you want to access the following bytes (chars) you have to use the address that is stored in `atr` in another `char*` and then use pointer arithmetics to access the following bytes (char), i.e. by using `memcpy` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: You need to allocate memory.

Comment: Declaring a pointer to char is not enough. The pointer has to point to some allocated memory. That is, you need to allocate the required memory and initialize at etc to point at it.

Comment: Do you have to use `char*`'s?  `std::string` would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Better simply use `std::string` if you can use c++ features.

Comment: You really haven't explained what you want to do. Are you trying to construct strings that consist of pairs of characters? Also, are you coding in C or C++ -- the answers are different.

Comment: @jhammond  It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C++, C does not let you overload operators, which is the feature responsible for `std::string` concatenation using operator `+`. Therefore, in C you get the sum of two character codes, and you write them into a character pointer. That is *not* what you want.

If the number of locations from which you are picking characters is fixed, you can construct C strings using initialization:

```
char _ts[] = { atr[0], atr[1], 0 };
char _t0[] = { atr[2], atr[3], 0 };
```

Note null terminators at the end, this is required when you wish to use `_ts` and `_t0` as C strings.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3DNA91)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use chars instead of string, here's your problem:
You didn't initialize your pointers. Try with `char* my_ptr = new char(atr[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

This function will make a string consisting of the specified two characters. Don't forget to `free` it when you're done with it.

```
char* makeString (char c1, char c2)
{
    char* buf = malloc(3);
    buf[0] = c1;
    buf[1] = c2;
    buf[2] = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
char* _ts = makeString (atr[0], atr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`_ts` and `_t0` are pointers to memory locations of type char.
on the right hand side of equal sign where you do `atr[0] + atr[1]` what is happening there is you are first de-referencing the memory locations of atr and (atr+1) and getting the values there.
note: atr+1 is 1 byte away from atr, because atr is of type char and the sizeof(char) is 1 byte.
so now you have two character values from atr[0] and atr[1] and even though they are of type char, those values can be added because in the C language the character type is really a 1 byte integer number between 0 and 255 based on the ascii table.  for example, the value of 'A' is decimal 65.  The value of 'a' is decimal 97.  Which is why something like this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char c1, c2, c3;

    c1 = 'A';   /* ascii value of 65 */
    c2 = 'd';   /* ascii value of 100 */

    printf("decimal value of c1 and c2 is %d and %d\n", c1, c2 );

    if (( c1 >= 65 ) && ( c1 <= 90 ))
    {
        printf("I know c1 contains a letter between capital A and capital Z,\n");
        printf("it's decimal value is %d which is the character %c\n", c1, c1 );
    }


    c1 = 'A';   /* ascii 65 */
    c2 = 'a';   /* ascii 97 */
    c3 = c2 - c1;
    printf("c1 = %c, c2 = %c\n", c1, c2 );
    printf(" c2 - c1 = %d, x%cx\n", c3, c3 );

    /* ascii of 97-65 = 32 == space character */

    c1 = 67;  /* set c1 to a capital C */
    printf(" c1 = decimal %d, it is character %c\n", c1, c1 );

    return 0;
}
```

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

With C99, code can use *compound literals*.  Code creates two 3-char arrays and populates them with elements of `atr[]`.

```
const char* atr = "abcd";

char* _ts = (char [3]) {atr[0], atr[1], '\0'};
char* _t0 = (char [3]) {atr[2], atr[3], '\0'};

puts(_ts);
puts(_t0);
```

Output

```
ab
cd
```

The pointers `_ts, _t0` are valid until the end of the block.